# iPhone: how to load objects *after* the main viewcontroller has appeared

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

Ok hopefully this is an easy question:

- I have a main viewcontroller that is loaded by the app delegate at application startup.
- This viewcontroller has some code in 'viewDidLoad' to create some non view type based objects (some sound/data objects). Aside from that it also loads a UIView.
- The sound/data objects take a while to create, but the app is quite functional without them for a start - so I want to load these objects after the UIView has loaded, but can't seem to figure out how.
- I have tried moving the appropriate code to viewDidAppear, but this is still called before the UIView actually appears on screen. Is there a function that is called after the viewcontroller actually starts displaying UIViews, or any other way to achieve what I want?

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has a similar problem, I found a way to solve it: use NSThread to load things in the background without pausing everything else.

There's a good simple example here: http://www.iphoneexamples.com/.